# What may cause a too long DS2482 reset pulse?

Tags: digital-logic, 1-wire

We experience odd behavior with the [DS2482-800 8-Channel 1-Wire Master](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ds2482-800.html). Often, when reconnecting a 1-Wire slave ([DS28E17 1-Wire-to-I2C Master Bridge](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ds28e17.html) in our case), communication does not resume because the Presence Pulse Detect bit (PPD) is not detected anymore. The presence pulse low time (\$t_{RSTL}\$) now exceeds its maximum of 630 μs. There is a 2k2 1-Wire pullup to 3V3 and only one slave device with a very short cable.

This arrangement is used to extend I2C communication similar to [this](https://www.analog.com/en/design-notes/extending-i2c-communication-distance-with-the-ds28e17.html) design note. Although this suggests \$R_{PUP}\$ is not needed, the DS28E17 datasheet states;

> The DS28E17 requires a pullup resistor of 2.2kΩ (max) at any speed.

It seems as if lower pullup values at the 1-Wire slave side worsens the problem. The drawback of higher pullup values is however that it allows for less long cables.

When this occurs, the reset pulse is too long at all channels whether a slave is connected or not. A device reset (command) does not change anything. Just waiting instead of busy polling does not help. Only a DS2482 power cycle will resolve it. We tested another slave type ([DS18B20+PAR 1-Wire Parasite-Power Digital Thermometer](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ds18b20par.html)) which does not cause this problem when reconnecting.

**DS2482 working situation:**
[image: Working situation]

**DS2482 problematic situation after reconnecting DS28E17 1-Wire slave:**
[image: Problematic situation]

What may cause such a long presence pulse after which the PPD-bit is no longer detected?

---

**Update**

The [DS2483 errata sheet](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ds18b20par.html) describes something that looks related. However, the workaround; no I2C (re)start during the Reset/Presence Pulse Cycle or not using the Active Pullup (APU) feature does not help.

Comment: To my knowledge, this is a bug in the DS2482-800. The only way to solve it is a power cycle on it, as you wrote. If you could gather new information on that, it would be great.

Comment: Oh, and it's not limited to the DS28E17. It happens with other onewire slaves as well, So I suspect it's about the bus itself.